# VB.NET: Error occurred after reloading the same form "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Good day!

I encounter a problem when reloading a form with using datagridview to load all data.

Error:

[image]

CODE:

```
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource

    Private Sub frmHistory_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Try
        CallDatabase()

        'Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
        'Dim ds As DataSet
        'Dim tables As DataTableCollection
        'Dim source1 As New BindingSource

        cnnOLEDB.ConnectionString = strConnectionString
        cnnOLEDB.Open()

        ds = New DataSet
        tables = ds.Tables
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [tblHistory]", cnnOLEDB) 'Change items to your database name
        da.Fill(ds, "tblHistory") 'Change items to your database name
        Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
        source1.DataSource = view
        gridHistory.DataSource = view

        gridHistory.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders
        gridHistory.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control

        gridHistory.Columns(0).Width = 40
        gridHistory.Columns(0).HeaderText = "No."
        gridHistory.Columns(1).Width = 80
        gridHistory.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Amount"
        gridHistory.Columns(2).Width = 70
        gridHistory.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Hours"
        gridHistory.Columns(3).Width = 70
        gridHistory.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Minutes"
        gridHistory.Columns(4).Width = 70
        gridHistory.Columns(4).HeaderText = "Pages"
        gridHistory.Columns(5).Width = 100
        gridHistory.Columns(5).HeaderText = "Date"

        cnnOLEDB.Close()
    'Catch ex As Exception
    '    Dim errMsg As String =
    '    "Error: {0} " & vbLf & "Please contact your Cyber Administrator."
    '    errMsg = String.Format(errMsg, ex.Message)

    '    MessageBox.Show(errMsg, "Application Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    '    Me.Hide()
    'End Try
End Sub
```

this line of code will get error every time I reload the form:

```
gridHistory.Columns(0).Width = 40
```

and so on...

If I remove that code it will work BUT the purpose of that code is to customize my datagridview because it takes huge space on the screen.

on my tblHistory these are the field

ID, amount, hours, minutes, pages, recordDate

if I add the code above this will be the ooutput:

No, Amount, Hours, Minutes, Pages, Date and all the column width will be divided depends the cell width on every column header.

Output:

Before I comment the code (gridHistory.Columns(0).Width = 40)

[image]

After I comment the code

[image]

See the difference?

Comment: Probably the problem is in the _reloading_ process. Some code present in the normal loading has been skipped here resulting in a grid without columns

Comment: Hi, then how will I solve it? any alternative? I thought when the form close all codes will refresh? I remove the code where the error execute and it works... but the column width will be the same on every column header

Comment: btw I update my post add more screenshot for better understaning.. Thanks

Comment: I am unable to reproduce what you describe. I have a button on form 1 that loads form 2 and using the supplied code never crashed closing and reloading the form numerous times. I question if the line you point to as the error is actually throwing this.

Comment: Looking at the line: `gridHistory.Columns(0).Width = 40`… there are only two objects that could throw this error: the `DataGridView` itself or a missing column. So, if you comment out only that line to set the width of the column and leave the next line: `gridHistory.Columns(0).HeaderText = "No."` to set the columns header text AND IT WORKS as it appears to in the second picture. Then both the `DataGridView` and column are valid and makes me question if the column width line is actually causing the error. What is `source1` used for?

Comment: @JohnG hi! I just copy the code from my reference since I can't find my old project that has DataGrid...This is the declaration of source 1: "Dim source1 As New BindingSource". Yup the Column.Width causing the error. If I comment that line the form works.

Comment: You said if you comment out just the line widths it will work?

Comment: I would take a closer look at the `DataView` view.

Comment: Again, it makes no sense for the width line to throw this error. As I said in my previous comment, there are only two objects on the line `gridHistory.Columns(0).Width = 40`  that COULD throw that error… the datagridview or the column in the datagridview. One of them is missing. If this were true, then the next line `gridHistory.Columns(0).HeaderText = "No."` would also fail even if the width line was commented out. So if you comment out the width line and leave the next line to set the header and it WORKS then something else is wrong.

Comment: Databinding is lazy and does not occur until the control becomes visible.  Load is too early.  Move the code into an event handler for the DGV's DataBindingComplete event so you can be sure that the expected columns are present.